# How do you include multiple entites in a Swift2 CoreData fetchrequest?

Tags: ios, swift2, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to populate a UITableview and I have a parent entity that should provide the section data and a child entity that should provide the cell data.  I have set up the "to many" relationship for the parent to child entities.

Comment: Posting what you have already tried will be a good start in helping people help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an entry A with one-to-many to B and you want to access both A & B then set the `fetchRequest` entry to A and you'll be able to access B through it's relationship pointer in A (A will have a `NSSet/NSOrderedSet` of B).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  I understand what you are telling me, but I'm brand new to Swift2.  Any chance you could give me an example of accessing attributes in B via the relationship pointer of A?  I'm still working through all the syntax land mines .  Thanks again.

Comment: In your .xcdatamodeld file when you set a one-to many relationship to another entry you need to give the relationship a name, that name is your pointer. so if you set it to be "products"  you could access A's B using A.products which will return either NSSet or NSOrderSet of Bs (depending if you set the relationship to be ordered or not). It's exactly the same as accessing any other entry attribute.